# How to remove prefix before passing - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Question is very simple but I cant get result.

I have *table of customers* with

> customer ID ASCU1...ASCU2...( customer ID is concatenated (custstr,
>   CONCAT(custstr, '.', customerID) AS custcode')

in Model(ASCU1) is not existed in customer table.

Problem is when I want to edit customer 
`(edit_customer(edit_customer(<?php echo $customer->custcode;?>))` nothing happening because of ID.

I want to show ASCU1 in datatable but to retrieve data I need to remove ASCU 1.

Hopefully I have explained my question if not please ask.

Comment: yes , i am asking. where is the code

Comment: you need a preg_replace function to remove string or characters from string expect number

Comment: Can you please give me example how Can I remove from ASCU1, ASCU and get only 1.

from controller I am getting <?php echo $customer->custcode;?>
custcode give me ASCU1 I need to remove from custcode.

got my point?

Comment: Should fix it that `ASCU` is stored in a different column.

Comment: Yes I have stored ASCU in db column but when I am passing 
delete_customer(ASCU-1) nothing happening I need to pass delete_customer(1) or if you have other solution please help me.